# How should I link a model to another model in MVC3?

Tags: entity-framework, model

I have a class called `Forum` and another class called `Thread`.

The class `Thread` contains a property that links it to a `Forum`. Should that property be some kind of ID (be it GUID, int or other):

```
public class Thread
{
    public GUID ID { get; set; }
    public GUID ForumID {get; set; }
}
```

or should it be of type Forum:

```
public class Thread
{
    public GUID ID { get; set; }
    public Forum ParentForum { get; set; }
}
```

What's the best way of doing it? Should it be the former as that would show up in the database?

PS.: I'm using Entity Framework

Comment: are you using Entity Frameworks?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I should have put that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about the design first: a `Thread` cannot exist without a `Forum`. Thus I would suggest you use:

```
public class Thread
{
    public GUID ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ForumId")]
    public Forum Forum { get; set; }

    public Guid ForumId {get; set; }
}
```

(I'm assuming your using Code First?)

I think the above will work, I haven't got VS 2010 in front of me here.

Comment: But is it necessary to have both `ForumID` and `Forum` in there? Shouldn't it be one or the other?

Comment: @Piers See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194146/how-should-i-link-a-model-to-another-model-in-mvc3/8194245#8194245) for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you expose the scalar property and the navigational property as follows.

```
public class Thread
{
    public GUID ID { get; set; }

    public GUID ForumID { get; set; }

    public virtual Forum Forum { get; set; }
}
```

If you are creating a `Thread` and you only know the `ForumID` you can easily create the thread if you expose the `ForumID`. Otherwise you either have to load the relavent `Forum` object from database or create a dummy object and attach it to the `ObjectContext/DbContext`.

Exposing the navigational property will help you when you need forum data to do some processing on the thread object.